# Is “I’m Mike” scam a popular metonym of "grandparent" scam?

Tags: contemporary-english

This question is related to my previous question asking for English equivalent to Japanese “It’s me” scam. The Asahi, a leading Japanese daily newspaper reported that the Consumer Agency is dispatching their staff to the U.S. FTC to study the latest trends of and countermeasures to consumer-related crimes such as the grandparent scam, in its May 9 issue under the headline, “The origin of grandparent scams – “I’m Mike” in U.S.”

It says,

> “The fraudulent crimes to swindle a large amount of money from the elderly by disguising as their son are prevailing as well in U.S., where the technique is called “**I’m Mike** (scam)." According to the Consumer Agency, Japanese swindler groups have imitated (or imported) the “I’m Mike” technique in U.S.

I’m curious to know if “I’m Mike” is a popular word as a metonym of grandparent scam in U.S. as the Asahi wrote. Have you ever heard of? If not, I'm going to write to the Asahi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never heard of it and I love reading about swindles and scams.

When I put it in google all the way to "i'm mike sca" the word scam doesn't even fill.

When I type the full phrase into google nothing describing the phrase as a scam comes up.  It may be something that was translated incorrectly or translated to make easier to reference.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169403/what-is-its-me-swindle-called-in-u-s-u-k-canada/169405#169405  They do not use a name but just  "grandma" or grandpa" and then wait for the elderly person to use their grandchild's name

Comment: I don’t either believe the cons use personal names such as Mike, Tom, and Jon. It’s silly for swindlers to use such a specific name, because the phone will be cut off on the instant it’s found a wrong name by the grandparent. So Japanese swindlers say "It's me, mom." I was very skeptical about the Asahi’s statement.